# Combine two pandas columns to form a new list on iteration

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set containing 240 columns. Columns:0,1 correspond to lat and long values resp. of a trajectory. Similarly Columns:2,3 correspond to a different trajectory. I want to create separate lists of each trajectory like traj1, traj2, traj3 etc.

I have tried using:

```
traj1 = list( zip( trajAll["0"], trajAll["1"] ) )
```

I have also tried selecting two columns of the data at a time and using tolist():

```
traj_01 = trajAll[ [ '0','1' ] ]

traj1 = traj_01.values.tolist()
```

Both codes serve the purpose for the first 2 columns of lat long which gives me traj1 only. I need to perform this in iteration for several pairs of columns in the dataframe 'trajAll' and each time I need a new list like traj2, traj3 etc

```
for i, j 

    j = i+1

    traj(i) = trajAll[['i','j']]
```

I expect to get:

```
traj1 = [ [28.3, 77.2],  [28.6, 77.1],  [..],  [..], ..]

traj2 = [ [28.5, 77.8],  [28.9, 78.5],  [..],  [..], ..]
```

as output and I need to use traj1, traj2, traj3 etc in functions